# Magento 2.X : what are people doing about different versions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, upgrade, magento2.2

After upgrading from ***2.1.9*** to **2.2.0** on two of our current magento sites, its apparent that the process is somewhat easy and difficult at the same time.

Yes composer makes going from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 is easier than ever before but it feels that so many things have broken. Even on a site, which is a pretty straight forward Magento 2 build. Lots of core changes and different functionality but also causing lots of bugs in the theme ( and trust me the theme isn't overly complex. )

**So to the question.**

My simple question is, what are people doing in regards to the upgrades, are you sticking with 2.1.9 and then leaving the client on this for the life span of the site ( obviously patching as time goes by. ) and then when a client is on 2.2 or 2.3 they will stay with that version for the duration of their site life span?

Or are they upgrading to 2.2 then 2.3 because if 2.2 is anything to go by 2.3 will be the same and again for 2.4 - it will just cause headache after headache.

Now I would be torn because, having the latest and greatest is always the way forward for me, but if it means pain to upgrade, why bother for a simple feature the client may not need? - but at the same time the upgrade might fix bugs that may never be patched and we are expected to upgrade to fix?

I feel as though as its question that no one really talks about or has asked.

Comment: Personally I have stayed on 2.1.9 at the most for my sites because of the same issues. Its on a todo list somewhere to upgrade but the process, as you point out, is not smooth. There are a lot of improvements that we rely on in the 2.2 update but we have to trade time to get it remotely working and theres no clue to how much time that will be. Hearing your experience has only made me more hesitant to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we are starting getting similar situation as was before with Magento 1.x when lot of stores stuck on 1.4 , 1.7 or even older for years. Then massive security issues starting to appear and lot of patches issued. Now some early adopters already stuck on Magento 2.0.x because they don't want to invest to not necessary features and same will happens with 2.1.x and 2.2.x - this is create huge issues for ecosystem, extension vendors and i think Magento Inc. itself, because they need to support all versions with at least security patches.

My opinion - with M2 you should always upgrade until we get version with 100% stable core (was around 1.7 for Magento 1), for now with hundreds of bugs in core functionality i don't see the way to stay and not upgrade.

Some good reading about versioning in Magento 2 :

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/software_versions.html
- http://alanstorm.com/why_semver_is_failing_in_magento_2/